# convert El Capitan .app to .dmg

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I want to install El Capitan in VirtualBox on my Mac already running El Capitan.

I found a tutorial on installing Yosemite in VirtualBox on a host running OSX Yosemite [here](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/08/run-osx-vm-virtualbox/). The first thing was to convert app to `.dmg` file like this:

```
gem install iesd
iesd -i /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app -o Desktop/yosemite.dmg -t BaseSystem
```

I tried finding the Install folder in `Applications` but there is none. So my question is how should I rewrite this code to convert `El Capitan.app` to `.dmg` on El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your install application installed, as OS X does not include that by default. Also, you mentioned that you want to install El-Capitan, and the command:

```
iesd -i /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app -o Desktop/yosemite.dmg -t BaseSystem
```

Would turn an Install **Yosemite** app, that you had to also install before. You need to go to the App Store, and download the app for El-Capitan.

Then, you would just re-write the path from Yosemite to El-Capitan. The command would look like this assuming the app is in the default location (Applications folder).

```
iesd -i /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ El\ Capitan.app -o Desktop/elcap.dmg -t BaseSystem
```

This would create **elcap.dmg** on your Desktop to use in Virtualbox

Answer (score -1):

Just like clearly written in the tutorial you referenced, you need to:

> Download it for free from the “Apple App Store”. You do need a Mac with a valid Apple-id for this.

So go to the `App Store`, search for `OS X El Capitan` and press `Download` button (make sure you have several GB free on your disk and time).

It is not folder `Install`, but a whole app called `Install El Capitan.app`.

<sup>By the way, you can easily find [guides for El Capitan](http://anadoxin.org/blog/creating-a-bootable-el-capitan-iso-image.html) on the Internet.</sup>